# Why do i get awful network speeds on Ubuntu 20.04 when they were fine on Windows 10? Is it a driver issue?

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, atheros

I recently switched to Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows 10 on my Lenovo B50-45 with a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 30). My Network speeds have always been normal on Windows (about 30mb/s, which is what my WiFi is supposed to have), but now, after switching to Ubuntu, speedtest.net shows a network speed of ~10kb/s and most Websites take up to 10mins to even load (This is all on Firefox Browser). The Internet still works fine on my Desktop(Windows 10 20H2) and Phone(Android 11).

I'm still learning my way around Ubuntu, so i don't really know how to fix this... The only thing i can guess is that this could be a driver issue, but i wouldn't know how to solve it... Can anyone here help me?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have been it :)

Comment: Good to know. I've posted it as an answer. Later you can upvote and accept the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not likely a driver issue.

Please check your router before anything else.

**WPA2-AES is preferred, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP**.

Yes, we're aware of the part about other devices working fine, that's not the point. The point is those are the recommended settings and desktop Linux is a lot more picky.